# How to prove that this particular function is continuous?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

This was an exam question from the topology course of a previous year.

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space and $f: X \to X$ be a continuous map. How that the map $g: X \to \mathbb{R} , x \mapsto d(x,f(x))$ is continuous.

I know several definitions of continuity and and I know that the the continuous image of a compact set is compact (and, by Heine-Borel, closed and bounded). I can't seem to apply these definitions and results to prove that $g$ is continuous, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you consider is the composition of $d:X\times X\to \mathbb R$ and the function $X\to X\times X$ given by $x\mapsto (x,f(x))$. Show that each of these is continuous. Notice that compactness is not used anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

The metric $d: X \times X \to [0,\infty)$ is continuous and $x \mapsto (x,f(x))$ is continuous. The composition of continuous maps is continuous $\ \square$